# Looking for a table of number of digits in local phone number per country

Tags: phone-number, reformatting, phonenumberutils

In order to reformat phone numbers, I would like to use a table saying how many digits to expect in the local phone numbers. It depends on countries: some countries have 10 digits for all local numbers (excluding country and area prefixes), some have more and some have less.
Having the length of the local number, we can check if it makes sense that the first digits are country code.
Is it such a table available?

Comment: Are you looking for this in a particular framework or are you asking for database design?

Answer (score 0):

The numbering plans are regulated by local authorities, so I don't thing there exists a global definition.

A possible starting points is the overview [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes) containing links to the national definitions, e.g. for [UK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_the_United_Kingdom#Format). On this example you see that there is in general case no single format per country.